# Issue with AppCompat and Themes in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

I recently created a new project with minSdkVersion 15, compiled and targetedSdkVersion 21, along with a couple of activities. I would like to use the default holo dark theme for my app and according to the documentation I just need to use Theme.AppCompat. When I test this on my personal phone (running 4.4.2), I get the dark holo theme and what I expect. However, when I run the latest nexus emulator with Lollipop, the theme and the controls look completely different. For example, the switch in Lollipop shows up just as a slider, without the text specified for the on/off states.

Is there a way for me to keep a consistent look and feel (of how it looks like on my phone) without having to worry about the app completely looking different on newer devices?

Edit:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppThemeDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "placeholder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Pics:

1. Lollipop/Emulator version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8QhX.png
2. Kitkat/Phone version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8QhX.png

Comment: Can you share a screenshot and the styles.xml files that you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many widget UIs have been updated to the new 'Material Design' look and feel with latest version of `appcompat-v7`, on purpose. So if you really want to resist the trend, you will have to manually override your widget UIs with your own background.

Comment: What would be the best practice for giving users a consistent UI experience/staying consistent then?

Comment: Keep your `appcompat-v7` up to date is one good way to always get latest UIs. But even the library is only able to apply consistent style up until some API levels (widget tinting is not available in older APIs). For those cases, you either have to sacrifice the consistent look and feel across API levels, or have to settle with some average (and manually applied) look and feel across API levels.